# Input checked depending on day of week

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of items a customer can choose from. I have set that the first method is always selected by default. But I want to achieve that depending on the day of the week different kind of method is chosen by default. I want something like this:

- From Monday to Wednesday `#method1` should be checked
- Thursday `#method2` should be checked
- Friday `#method3` should be checked

How can I do that with PHP and Javascript/jQuery?

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <input checked="checked" class="validate" value="value1" id="method1" type="radio">
        <label for="method1">Method1</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input class="validate" value="value2" id="method2" type="radio">
        <label for="method2">Method2</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input class="validate" value="value3" id="method3" type="radio">
        <label for="method3">Method3</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: why do you need php ?where did you use php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the current weekday from a date using `getDay()`. From there you can use `prop('checked')` to set the relevant radio. Try this:

```
var day = new Date().getDay();
switch (day) {
    case 1:
    case 2: 
    case 3:
        $('#method1').prop('checked', true);
        break;
    case 4:
        $('#method2').prop('checked', true);
        break;
    case 5:
        $('#method3').prop('checked', true);
        break;
    default:
        console.log('its a weekend!')
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mfjLj1s1/)